# Problems with a Class Assignment

Tags: javascript

I am enrolled in a Full Stack Developer program here soon, and we have a pre course assignment. I am at the end of the course work and just need to figure out the issues I am having with the assignment.

Here are the issues:

The card does not 'flip' to show the front of the card
The image of the front of the card does not show
The cardsInPlay array does not have any cards in it, however, when you click on one card the JS reacts like there is already a card in the array when there should not be.
Below is my code in JS for the assignment. Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
var cards = [
{
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-hearts.png"
},
{
    rank: "queen",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/queen-of-diamonds.png"
},
{
    rank: "king",
    suit: "hearts",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-hearts.png"
},
{
    rank: "king",
    suit: "diamonds",
    cardImage: "images/king-of-diamonds.png"
}
];

var cardsInPlay = [];

var flipCard = function() {
    var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log("User flipped " + (cards[cardId].rank));
    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
    checkForMatch();
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
};

var checkForMatch = function() {
    this['src'] = (cards[0,1,2,3].cardImage);
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2 && cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
        alert("You found a match!");
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, try again");
    }
};

var createBoard = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.setAttribute('src', "images/back.png");
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
        document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
};

createBoard();
```

Comment: `this['src'] = (cards[0,1,2,3].cardImage)` What were you hoping this would do?

Comment: var checkForMatch = function(cardId) {
this['src'] = (cards[cardId].cardImage);
//....

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp `this` points to `window` in this context, so that would also not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question <strike>should produce an error when you run it (*see the console*)</strike>  has a major problem at the line `this['src'] = (cards[0,1,2,3].cardImage);`

The `this` in this function which is just called from the `flipCard` refers to the `window` object and not the `img` that was clicked.  (*i assumed you were just testing things*)

To show the image you would need to assign it in the `flipCard` method to the `img`. (*and since you are learning, you should be converting the `data-id` to a number*)

```
var flipCard = function() {
    var cardId = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-id'),10); // use parseInt to convert to integer
    console.log("User flipped " + (cards[cardId].rank));
    this.src = cards[cardId].cardImage; // add this to set the image
    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
    checkForMatch();
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
};
```

besides that there is a concept error in your tests. Whenever you click on the image you add that card in the `cardsInPlay` array, but you do not test if the image is already flipped. So clicking twice on an image will add it twice and since it has the same `rank` (*which is what you save and test*) it would return a match.

Comment: That wouldn't actually produce an error (unless strict mode), but it's certainly not going to do whatever the OP was thinking.

Comment: @squint you are right. It also looks that the last index passed will be used which i was not aware.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli this works! Thanks that was a better explanation then what I was hearing from other people in my class. So my code still says my alert when I click on one card without clicking on a second card. Would this possibly have to do with the if...else statement?

Comment: @T.Evans no, that is because you do an `if`/`else` whenever you check. So if there are 2 cards and are of the same rank you alert something, otherwise (*when either there are not exactly two cards or they are of different rank*) you alert something else. In your case on first click the `.length` is 1 so it goes to the `else`.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, So even though I have the `if (cardsInPlay.length === 2 && cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1])` it still wants to run through the function without meeting the parameter, set to 2, when 1 card is selected? So I would need to change the `.lenght` to something else and add `.rank` to `cardsInPlay[0]` and `cardsInPlay[1]`?

Or would it need to be `(cards[cardId].rank)`?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli maybe I am not understanding what I need to do here I get that there needs to be 2 cards in the array and they have to have same rank to match, but with the parameter I set in the `if/else` makes the `.length` 2 then why would it match the 1st card without having a second one in the array? The directions for this assignment portion aren't exactly clear on my end

Comment: @T.evans when you click on one card you get the **Sorry, try again** alert, right?

Comment: What you describe in your previous message is the condition to show the ***You found a match*** alert. They way your test code is now, it will always alert one of the two messages depending on the conditions met (*and your if is testing two conditions*).

Comment: @T.Evans what you really want, is for the messages to appears in either case only when two card have been clicked. So you should first test if there are two elements if that is true then check for correct rank and show the messages. So two `if`s nested. In pseudo code `if (cardlength==2){  if (rand1==rank2) {alert correct} else {alert wrong} }`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli,  ok cool, so then my 'rank' values should be `cardsInPlay.rank` or `cards[cardId].rank`? The `cards[cardId].rank` is what was pushed to the array `cardsInPlay`. They have not covered what exactly the code looks like once you push into an array, so those are the 2 examples that I could think of. Seems like I am missing a bunch of info from this prework.

Comment: you have already pushed the `rank` in the `cardsInPlay` array. So the original test should work `cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, Thank you for your help! Sorry I am new and really trying to learn this all, I have been doing nothing but JS for the last week and eventually I will have it